# Weak law of large number and asymptotically almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $E_n$ be an probability event which depends on $n$. Based on the book I read, Tao's Random Matrix Theory, an event $E_n$ holds asymptotically almost surely if it holds with probability $1-o(1)$, i.e., $$\textbf{P}(E_n) \ge 1 - o(1)$$

Suppose $X_i$'s are iid copies of $X$ where $\mathbf{E}X=0$ and $\mathbf{E}X^2=1$. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
Then the weak law of large number says that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \textbf{P}(|S_n| \le \epsilon n ) = 1 $$

From here, can we say that 
$$ S_n = o(1)n $$
asymptotically almost surely?
I can see that for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ (independent with $n$)
$$ S_n = \epsilon n $$
holds asymptotically almost surely as the weak law of large number says
$$ \textbf{P}(|S_n| \le \epsilon n ) = 1 - o(1) $$
But not sure whether it is possible to relate $\epsilon$ with $n$.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the event $E_n$ in terms of $S_n$ that you wish to demonstrate that it holds asymptotically almost surely?

Comment: I may be missing something, but it  doesn't seem to make sense to me. "Asymptotically almost surely" applies to a _sequence_ of events, not an event, while $S_n=o(1)n$ is just an event, not a sequence of events.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you for your comments. I should've ask in that way. Please see page 124 of LINK(https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/matrix-book.pdf), eqn(2.67)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I should've ask in that way. But I wasn't sure. Sorry I am not familiar with the concept of aas. Please see page 124 of LINK(https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/matrix-book.pdf), eqn(2.67)/

Comment: I believe in this case, $E_n = \{ S_n = o(1)n \}$.

Comment: @induction601 That doesn't make sense. Think about what $o(1)$ means - $\{S_n=o(1)n\}$ is not a sequence of events. (The $n$ is a "dummy variable"; the event is just $\{\lim_nS_n/n=0\}$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I assume what you're saying is correct. But this is what I see. $S_n = o(1)n$ is just saying $|S_n/n| \le g(n)$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = 0$. Thus I am not sure how you put $\lim$ into it? I believe $\{\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n/n = 0\}$ and $\{|S_n/n| \le g(n)\}$ are different.